# How to remove new line characters from data rows in Presto/AWS Athena?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, replace, amazon-athena, presto

I'm querying some tables on Athena (Presto SAS) and then downloading the generated CSV file to use locally. Opening the file, I realised the data contains new line characters that doesn't appear on AWS interface, only in the CSV and need to get rid of them. Tried using the function `replace(string, search, replace) → varchar` to skip the newline char replacing `\n` for `\\n` without success:

```
SELECT
    p.recvepoch, replace(p.description, '\n', '\\n') AS description
FROM
    product p
LIMIT 1000
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem was that the underlying table data doesn't actually contains `\n` anywhere, instead, the actual newline character, which is represented by `char(10)`. I was able to achieve the expected behaviour using the `replace` function passing it as parameter:

```
SELECT
    p.recvepoch, replace(p.description, chr(10), '\n') AS description
FROM
    product p
LIMIT 1000
```

Comment: Also, If one needs to achieve the same behaviour with tab characters, replace `char(9)` by `\t` as well.

Comment: carriage return is `chr(13)` https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/string.html

Comment: you can also use `REGEXP_REPLACE(p.description, '\n', '')`